# Расчет меры в зависимости от измерения (MDX)

Tags: visual-studio

У меня создается мера в SSAS. В ней в конструкции CASE определяется, показывать значение или нет (значения показываются только для листовых и не нулевых элементов). Расписано все для измерения Номенклатуры. Все работает хорошо. Но эта мера еще может выводится в разрезе других измерений, например, Контрагентов. Если просто дописать еще условия WHEN в конструкции CASE, то работает только Номенклатура. Пробовалось так же к первым условиям добавить вторые при помощи OR - тогда работает не совсем верно и только, когда в разрезе одновременно Номенклатуры и Контрагентов. Не приходит на ум как реализовать все правильно.

Вот код создания меры:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Цена с завода шт]
 AS CASE 
WHEN IsLeaf([Номенклатура].[Номенклатура]) THEN [Measures].[Цена с завода шт расч]
WHEN  [Номенклатура].[Номенклатура].level.ordinal = 0 OR 
IsEmpty(([Номенклатура].[Номенклатура], [Measures].[Сумма с завода])) 
THEN NULL
--WHEN IsLeaf([Контрагенты].[Контрагенты]) THEN [Measures].[Цена с завода шт расч]
--WHEN [Контрагенты].[Контрагенты].level.ordinal = 0 OR
--IsEmpty(([Контрагенты].[Контрагенты], [Measures].[Сумма с завода])) THEN NULL
    ELSE ''
END,
```

Answer (score 1):

Может, все же SCOPE, на вашем примере примерно так

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Цена с завода шт]
AS NULL;
SCOPE ([Measures].[Цена с завода шт])  
  SCOPE (DESCENDANTS([Номенклатура].[Номенклатура].[All],,LEAVES))  
    THIS = [Measures].[Цена с завода шт расч]
  END SCOPE;
  SCOPE (DESCENDANTS([Контрагенты].[Контрагенты].[All],,LEAVES))  
    THIS = [Measures].[Цена с завода шт расч]
  END SCOPE;
END SCOPE;
```

Смысл - будет показываться мера `[Measures].[Цена с завода шт расч]` когда идет анализ по листовым элементам **Номенклатуры** или **Контрагента**. В иных случаях - NULL.